# Using Sed or Script to Inline Edit Values in Data Files With Variable Spacing

Tags: regex, bash, sed, formatting, overwrite

I have a number of scripts that replace variables separate by white space.

e.g.

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g' filename.conf
```

But say I have

```
#NAME       Weight    Age  Name
Boss        160.000   43   BOB
```

The below data is made more readable if it stays within the current alignment, so to speak.  So if I'm writing a new `double`, I'd like to only overwrite the width of each of the fields.

My questions are:
 1. How to I capture the patterns between values to preserve spaces?
 2. Does `sed` feature a way to force a shell variable say `${FOOBAR}` to be a certain width?
 3a. If so how do I define this replace field width?
 3b. If not what program in Linux is best suited for this truncation assuming I use a mix of number and string data?

**EDIT 1**
Let me give a couple more examples.
Let's say my file is:

```
#informative info on this config var.
VAR1 131  comment second_comment

#more informative info
VAR2 3.4  13132    yet_another_comment

#FOO    THE VALUE   WARNING
Foo     5.6         donteditthis_comment

#BAR    ANOTHER VALUE  WARNING
Bar     6.5            donteditthis_comment

#Yet another informative comment
VAR3   321
```

in my bash script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Vars -- real script will have vals in arrays as 
#multiple identically tagged config files will be altered
FOO='Foo'
BAR='Bar'
FOO_VAL_NEW='33.3333'
BAR_VAL_NEW='22.1111'
FILENAME='file.conf'

#Define sed patterns
#These could be inline, but are defined here for readability as they're long.
FOO_MATCH=${FOO}<...whatever special character can be used to capture whitespace...>'[0-9]*.*[0-9]*'
FOO_REPLACE=${FOO}<...whatever special characters to output captured whitespace...>${FOOD_VAL_NEW}
BAR_MATCH=${BAR}<...whatever special character can be used to capture whitespace...>'[0-9]*.*[0-9]*'
BAR_REPLACE=${FOO}<...whatever special characters to output captured whitespace...>${BAR_VAL_NEW}

#Do the inline edit ... will be in a loop to handle multiple 
#identically tagged config files in full-fledged script.
sed -i "s/${FOO_MATCH}/${FOO_REPLACE}/g" ${FILENAME}
sed -i "s/${BAR_MATCH}/${BAR_REPLACE}/g" ${FILENAME}
```

My expected output is:

```
#informative info on this config var.
VAR1 131  comment second_comment

#more informative info
VAR2 3.4  13132    yet_another_comment

#FOO    THE VALUE   WARNING
Foo     33.3333     donteditthis_comment

#BAR    ANOTHER VALUE  WARNING
Bar     22.1111        donteditthis_comment

#Yet another informative comment
VAR3   321
```

Currently my script works...  but there's a couple of annoyances/dangers.

*PROBLEM 1*

Currently to match the tag, I include the exact whitespace characters after it.  E.g. for the given example I would define

```
FOO='Foo     '
```

...as I'm unsure of how to capture ws characters and then output them in the the replace field.

This is nice for me, as I know I'm going to keep the spaces to the first field the same, to maintain readability.  But if one of my users (this is for a public project) writes their own file and writes:

```
#FOO    THE VALUE   WARNING
Foo  22.0
```

Now my script is broken for them.  I need to capture the whitespace chars in my match pattern, then output them in my output pattern.  That way it will play nice with my file (optimally spaced for readability) but if someone wants to muck things up and not space things nicely it will still work for them as well, preserving their current spaces.

*PROBLEM 2*

Okay so we've read a tag and injected a consistent amount of spaces after it for the replace, based on what we found with a regex in the match.

But now I need to replace fields within the string.

Currently my script does this.  However it isn't the clean style I show above in my desired input.  For the above script, for example, I'd get:

```
#informative info on this config var.
VAR1 131  comment second_comment

#more informative info
VAR2 3.4  13132    yet_another_comment

#FOO    THE VALUE   WARNING
Foo     33.3333        donteditthis_comment

#BAR    ANOTHER VALUE  WARNING
Bar     22.1111           donteditthis_comment

#Yet another informative comment
VAR3   321
```

Well the values are right, but all that work for readability is ruined.... argghhh.  Now if I opened the files in `emacs` and pressed the `insert key` I would be able to `arrow` over to the '3' in  the `Foo` tagged value and then start typing the new value and get the output file I listed as desired.  I want my `sed` inline edit to do the same thing... (Maybe as Kent showed this is possible with `column`?)

I want it to only overwrite on the trailing end.  Further, I want it to start the next field (let's say I do end up editing the warning) at the same column it started at in the old file.

Put more simply I want to do a variant `sed -i "s/${MATCH}/${REPLACE}/g" ${FILENAME}` that writes replacement variables to a tagged line, starting at the same column that entry is at in the CURRENT version of the config. file.

This requires both saving the spaces and somehow coding to only write on the trailing end and pad the output so that the next entry stays in the same starting column if my new value's string is shorter than the old one.

In order to improve upon my current solution it is crucial to both maintain the column start position for each piece of data in a tagged entry and secondly to be able to match a tag with an arbitrary amount of trailing whitespace (which must be preserved)... these are trivial operations in a text editor (see the `emacs` example above) with the help of the insert key, but more complicated in the script scenario.

This way:
 1. I make sure the values can be written no matter how other users space their file.
 2. If users (like myself) do bother to match the fields column-wise to the comment above to improve readability, then the script won't mess this up, as it only writes on the trailing side.

Let me know if this is unclear at all.

If this can't be done or is overly onerous with `sed` alone, I'd be open to an efficient `perl` or `python` subscript that my `bashscript` would call, although obviously an inline solution (if concise and understandable) is preferable, if possible.

Comment: what if the new was `555.555555555555` and the old was `160.000`? also try do the substitution and pipe the output to `column -t`

Comment: @Kent: Post that as answer.

Comment: I agree with anubhava, sounds like you're close to having a working fix. Might want to write it as a pair of bash functions, with the double one being roun through `bc` with the old `+.5` trick if the value is too long, so as to round, not truncate (which in most of my cases is more proper).

Comment: @anubhava I added it as an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! that's just what I need... The only thing I feel the question lacks, it that I don't know the constant at compile time, I just know the name of the variable tag.... so I would want something more like `sed "s/${BOSS_TAG}[0-9]*.*[0-9]*   /" f|column -t` .... but what would be really cool is if I could capture the current space pattern so that it preserved it (preserving readability), but that it would still work even if someone went and changed the # of spaces.  In that case readability would, of course, go down the drain, but it'd be better than breaking.

Comment: @Kent: Great +1 to your answer.

Comment: In other words, can you rework your example to use the name of the tag (let's call that `${FOO}` or something similar and capture the current spaces and overwrite staying faithful to those spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one of your sample datasets, you can get

```
$ doit Weight 160 7.555555 <<\EOD
#NAME Weight Age Name
Boss  160.000   43   BOB
Me    180       25   JAKE
EOD
#NAME  Weight          Age  Name
Boss   7.555555555555  43   BOB
Me     180             25   JAKE
$
```

with this function:

```
$ doit () 
{ 
    awk -v tag=$1 -v old=$2 -v new=$3 '
                NR==1 { for (i=0;i++<NF;) field[$i]=i }  # read column headers

                $field[tag] == old {
                        $field[tag] = new
                }

                {print}
        ' | column -t
}
```

the useful part being loading the column headers into the `field` name->column map.  With `tag` being `"Weight"`, `field[tag]` evaluates to `2` for this input so `$field[tag]` is `$2` i.e. the second field, the Weight column.

To answer your questions as asked:

My questions are:

> 1. How do I capture the patterns between values to preserve spaces?

Because of what [Kent pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011272/using-sed-or-script-to-inline-edit-values-in-data-files-with-variable-spacing#comment29797219_20011272), it's probably best to regenerate spacing correct for the new data.  If preserving the exact input spacing where at all possible, forcing lines with replacement values to have different alignment for some values, I'd say ask that again as a separate "no, really, help me here" question.

> 2. Does sed feature a way to force a shell variable say ${FOOBAR} to be a certain width?

sed's Turing complete, but that's as close to a feature as it's got for this.  Sardonic humor aside, the only correct answer here is "no".

> 3b. If not what program in Linux is best suited for this truncation assuming I use a mix of number and string data?

Kent got that one. I didn't know about `column`, I get questions answered here I didn't even know to ask.  For the value location and substitution awk should do you just fine.

Answer (score 3):

the `column` may help you, see the example below if it was you are looking for:

```
kent$  cat f
#NAME       Weight    Age  Name
Boss        160.000   43   BOB

kent$  sed 's/160.000/7.0/' f|column -t          
#NAME  Weight  Age  Name
Boss   7.0     43   BOB

kent$  sed 's/160.000/7.7777777777/' f|column -t
#NAME  Weight        Age  Name
Boss   7.7777777777  43   BOB
```

Comment: That's almost there to what I need... can you get it to capture the spaces and to work with an arbitrary tag name/arbitrary decimal value for the first field (i.e. by using `${TAG_NAME}`, some capture pattern for the first set of white space characters, and then `[0-9]*.*[0-9]*` for the field in the current value position of `sed - 's/current/new' f`)?? (see above comments...)

Comment: @JasonR.Mick I don't think I understood your requirement. could you please make an example in your question with input and output? If you want to use shell variable in sed line, use double quotes. `sed "..." file`

Comment: What I mean is that I want to be able to replace an arbitrary number field with a value in the script (so a regex is needed).  Assume that "BOB" could be something else... it's just a variable string.  I want to preserve the first set of spaces exactly --- whatever the current value is --- and the remaining set of spaces I want to overwrite only in the trailing direction, if necessary.  I'll add a clear description to the question shortly, but for now I'm rating you, because your answer is close to what I need.